# how to get sha1sum to output binary?

Tags: linux

I need to base64 encode a binary sha1 hash.  What is the best way to do this?  I imagine this would involve piping binary data into `base64`.  Unfortunately `sha1sum` does not have a binary output option.  Any ideas?

This is what I need to do:

```
echo mydata|sha1sum --binary-output|base64
```

sha1sum does not have a --binary-output option though.

Comment: How did binary creep into this?

Comment: I believe that jcalfee314 is saying that he wants to base64 encode an actual SHA1 hash value, rather than the hex representation thereof that the `sha1` program outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try converting hex to base64. This answer is one option.  There are a number of other implementations.

[How can I convert from hex to base64?](https://superuser.com/questions/158142/how-can-i-convert-from-hex-to-base64)

Answer (score 13):

Maybe something like:

```
echo mydata | sha1sum | xxd -r -p | base64
```

... would solve your problem.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82561/convert-a-hex-string-to-binary-and-send-with-netcat for similar question.

Comment: Beautiful! This _also_ works flawlessly under macOS Big Sur Beta (in late 2020).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `openssl` to Calculate`SHA-1` and `-binary` output the digest in binary form.

Last piping convert binary-digest to Base-64.

```
echo -n mydata | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | openssl base64
```

##### Explanation

###### Sending data (`mydata` in this case) to STDOUT:

```
echo -n mydata
```

`-n` flag remove new line (`\n`) from output.

###### Calculating `SHA-1` via OpenSSL:

```
 openssl dgst -sha1
```

However, this command displays the `SHA-1` in HEX mode, and for binary, the `-binary` flag needs to be added:

```
openssl dgst -binary -sha1
```

###### Convert `SHA-1` to `Base-64`:

```
openssl base64
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.